# Subscript of math equation in R documentation

Tags: r, documentation, rd

I'm trying to insert an equation in to an R documentation such that:

```
\deqn{p_{x}(1)=Pr(y=1|x)}
```

but it does come out as I expected where x is a subscript of p.

Does anybody know the reason OR how to subscript p in R documentation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The subscript will only render properly in the pdf version of your documentation, the HTML version is ASCII only as far as I know. To provide both a latex version of your equation for the pdf as well as a simplified equation for the html help, you can use both arguments of `\deqn{<<latex>>}{<<plain>>}`. Take a look for example at the [documentation of the `` `geigen `` package](https://github.com/cran/geigen/blob/master/man/geigen.Rd) for a few examples of providing both:

```
\deqn{A x = \lambda Bx}{A*x = lambda B*x}
\deqn{(A,B) = (Q S Z^H, Q T Z^H)}{(A,B) = (Q*S*Z^H, Q*T*Z^H)}
```

Comment: In addition to basic ASCII, the HTML version can produce Greek letters and a few other symbols such as the square root sign. I'm not sure how this gets rendered in the terminal if you view the help directly from a command in R.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
\ifelse{html}{\out{p_<sub>x</sub>(1)=Pr(y=1|x)}}{\eqn{p_x(1)=Pr(y=1|x)}}
```